# What to write in this Note model to detect whether the current user is doctor or patient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used devise gem in my project. I have a note model associated with user and appointment model.

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_presence_of :description, :message => "Please enter at least 5 characters"
 belongs_to :appointment
 belongs_to :user


 before_create do
   self.user_id = appointment.patient_id if (condition)
   self.user_id = appointment.doctor_id if (condition)
 end
```

end

What condition to write so as to determine whether I have created note as patient or doctor??

Comment: you can try with `user.is_a?(Patient)` or `user.is_a?(Doctor)`

Comment: My user model is like this: 
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base

enum role: [:patient, :doctor]
end

Comment: That depends on your business rule. How your business rule define which one is patient which one is doctor?

Comment: I have used enum as roles

Comment: I would say you should use Single Table Inheritance, it will make your life so much easier.

Comment: So your doctors cannot get sick and be patients? :) I don't think being a patient should be role in the users table. It's just a role in an appointment. Can you put your Appointment model? I think you can make a better design

Answer (score 1):

If you're using enum to work with your roles, then you can query them by name, that's to say `user.patient?` would return true if such user is a patient, same case for doctor.

So you could add that to your before_create callback:

```
before_create do
  self.user_id = appointment.patient_id if user.patient?
  ...
end
```

Maybe you could get the role of the user and use it to get the appointment id dynamically, like:

```
before_create do
  self.user_id = appointment.public_send("#{self.user.role}_id")
end
```

This way you avoid repetition on having to specify one by one each role.